# HTTP GET Request Returning Null? (Java)

Tags: java, json, http, url

I am using the following code to create an HTTP GET request:

```
URL obj = new URL(pl.getConfig().getString("Database URL") + player.getName());
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        Logger.getLogger("Minecraft").info(inputLine); //Logs null

        Gson gsonData = new Gson();
        MinecladJson jsonData = gsonData.fromJson(inputLine, MinecladJson.class); //Returns null (because inputLine is null)
        PlayerData jsonPlayerData = jsonData.getPlayer(); //Crash here
```

Unfortunately, the variable `inputLine` appears to be null, causing a NullPointerException in my code. Even worse, the address works fine in my browser and returns this:

```
{"player":{"balance":0,"permissions":["ultracosmetics.recievechest","ultracosmetics.openmenu"],"stats":{"playerKills":0,"deaths":0,"minutesPlayed":0},"achievements":{"firstJoin":false},"joinMessage":"&8[&9&l+&r&8] %r&7%p","leaveMessage":"&8[&9&l-&r&8] %r&7%p","rank":"default","firstJoin":"2016-07-01T02:37:14.458Z"},"content":{"chatFormat":"%r&7%p: %m","chatCensor":["testcensor"],"chatPrefixes":{"mage":"&5MAGE ","warrior":"&3WARRIOR ","chief":"&2CHIEF ","sage":"&7SAGE ","default":"","developer":"&9&lDEV ","moderator":"&6MOD "},"currencyName":"Coins","saveRate":30000,"cacheResetRate":1200000,"allowedCharacters":"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!~*.,/][()=+@#$%\"';:_`^&{}\\|<>?","tabHeader":"&8&lMineclad &r&9Network","tabFooter":"&7Mineclad.co"},"uuid":"559f6d32c2b740c9bc843dd54a55b39c"}
```

The stack trace:

```
[09:16:54 WARN]: java.lang.NullPointerException
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at com.techurify.minecladPlugin.event.player.PlayerJoinListener.onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinListener.java:56)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:300)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:501)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:486)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerList.onPlayerJoin(PlayerList.java:317)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerList.a(PlayerList.java:144)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.LoginListener.b(LoginListener.java:115)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.LoginListener.E_(LoginListener.java:53)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:224)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.ServerConnection.c(SourceFile:187)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:762)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:360)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:646)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:550)
[09:16:54 WARN]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I was wondering:

1. Why this is happening
2. And how to fix it

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace and indicate the line in your code where the exception originates.

Comment: It is impossible for `inputLine` to be null in this code other than at the end of the read loop, where you aren't using it any more.

Comment: @EJP Yeah, that's why I'm very confused.

Comment: @JimGarrison Updated!

Comment: Yeah, I logged `inputLine` and it's null. `jsonData` is null because `inputLine` is null. In the docs it says: returns:
`an object of type T from the string. Returns null if json is null.`

Comment: You're logging, and using, the line after the loop has exited. *Of course* it's null by then. Otherwise you would still be inside the loop. You should be using the response that you've built up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe instead of

```
MinecladJson jsonData = gsonData.fromJson(inputLine, MinecladJson.class);
```

You want

```
MinecladJson jsonData = gsonData.fromJson(response.toString(), MinecladJson.class);
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You accumulated individual response lines into `response`, but then attempted to extract the object from `inputLine`, which will always be `null` at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You are logging `inputLine` but I assume you want to log `response`.

For leaving the while loop `inputLine` has to be null, hence it makes me no wonder that you get that result when you print `inputLine`:

```
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 
        // leave while loop if inputLine == in.readLine() == null

        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    Logger.getLogger("Minecraft").info(inputLine); //Logs null
```